# Formatting using destructuring and Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting a new project in React and my API returns me a JSON where the format is not what I want for meetings. I've tried to use destructuring and `Object.entries`. What I have:

```
 {
        "meetings": [
            {
                "room1": DC13,
                "room2": AP47,
            }
        ],
        "teachers": [
            {
                "name: "Patrick",
                "speciality":"Math"
            },
           ...
        ],
        "alumni": [
            {
                "firstName": "Joe",
                "lastName":"Luis"
            },
            ...
        ]
      
    }
```

What I want:

```
   {
            "meetings": [
                {
                    "name": room1,
                    "location": DC13,
                },
                {
                    "name": room2,
                    "location": AP47,
                },

            ],
            "teachers": [
                {
                    "name: "Patrick",
                    "speciality":"Math"
                },
               ...
            ],
            "alumni": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Joe",
                    "lastName":"Luis"
                },
                ...
            ]
          
        }
```

What I've tried but not working:

```
const data= {meetings, teachers, alumni}
const newData = Object.entries(meetings).reduce((acc,name,location])=>acc.concat({name,location}),[]))
```

and then use this newData for manipulation after.

Comment: Can you double check for typos in this post?  I see a typo right away but that might not be what your code actually has.

Comment: The API is weird. Would the `meetings` array ever contain multiple objects?

Comment: @Bergi, I agree it is. No the `meetings` only has 1 object:  {......}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `map` here would be cleaner than `reduce`, so here's a working solution using `map`.

```
const data = { meetings, teachers, alumni };
data.meetings = Object.entries(data.meetings[0]).map(([key, value]) => ({
  "name": key,
  "location": value,
}))
```

Comment: do you mean `data.meetings[0]` instead of `receive` ??

Comment: @Etopli yes; I've edited the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: do you know why when I try to `console.log(newData)` where `newData=data.meetings =Object...` I get 2 arrays -> 0: `{name:'name', location:'room1'}`  and 1: `{name:'location', location: DC13'}` but `console.log (Object.entries(...))` gives me the good results. I wanted to put that in a new variable, so it would be easier to manipulate it after

Comment: @Etopli Hmm I'm not sure why that's happening. Try assigning newData like this:
`const newData = { ...data, meetings: Object.entries(...) }`.

Comment: @Etopli I noticed you're new here, so welcome! No pressure, but if one of the answers, mine or the other answer, helped you solve the problem, feel free to (though it's not strictly necessary!) mark that one as the "accepted answer." it will make it easier for people who come across the question in the future to solve their problem, and it gives credit to the answerer. Again though, this is completely optional.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you the desired output. It maps it each meeting and restructures the object by mapping its entry into a new object with the `name` and `location` keys.

```js
const data = {
    meetings: [
        {
            room1: "DC13",
            room2: "AP47",
        }
    ],
    teachers: [
        {
            name: "Patrick",
            speciality: "Math",
        },
    ],
    alumni: [
        {
            firstName: "Joe",
            lastName: "Luis",
        },
    ],
}

const newData = {
  ...data,
  meetings: data.meetings.map(meeting =>
    Object.entries(meeting)
      .map(([name, location]) =>
        ({name, location})
      )
    )
}

console.log(newData);
```